# django-formtools load initial values for modelformset

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-formwizard

I am trying to load an initial values for ModelFormSet within SessionWizardView, I tried loading initial values for ModelFormSet without the SessionWizardView and everything is working but with it, it's giving me this error:

> *KeyError at /en/agreement/4/edit/ 0*

Here is my code

```
class AgreementView(SessionWizardView):

    formset = modelformset_factory(model=Agreement, form=CreateAgreementsFormSet)
    form_list = [formset]
    template_name = 'app_name/template.html'

    def get_form_initial(self, step):

        initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
        if step == '0':
            initial.update([{'agreement': '4', 'description': '2'},
                            {'agreement': '4', 'description': '2'},
                            {'agreement': '4', 'description': '2'}])

        return self.initial_dict.get(step, initial)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary expects Key and Value. Here is what you are doing wrong:

```
  initial.update([{'agreement': '4'},
                        {'agreement': '4'},
                        {'agreement': '4'}])
```

You had forgotten to add a column between `'agreement'` and `'4'`

Comment: I was writing the question fast i have added it and i am getting the error

`initial.update([{'agreement': '4', 'description': '2'}])`

` KeyError at /en/agreement/4/edit/
0`

Comment: I have fixed the question

Comment: Nope, it's giving me KeyError at /en/agreement/4/edit/ 0

Comment: That's an error different from your question. You'd have to show the StackTrace and what you have in your `View` and probably `forms` since you mentioned form in your question

Comment: The ModelFormSet is working fine if i will just put extra=1 but when i want to load it with initial it do not work. it's always a keyError with is 0 yet i don't have 0 passed i don't know why this is related to forms or other views

Comment: `initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})` implies `initial_dict` returns a dictionary, Why are you updating it with a list? and why can't u pass the initial parameter you are updating as the fall-back argument?

Comment: ModelFormSet can be more then one set of dict which require a list of dict this is why i am passing a list. and i am not sure what do you mean as a fall-back argument.